# wait for execution of two ajax requests success functions in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have two ajax calls that are using `GET`, each one having a different `success` function.

I want to wait for the response of both requests and the execution of both success functions and then I need to execute another function?

How can I obtain this behavior?

I tried using `$q.all` but what this does is to wait for ajax requests to finish and then calls my third function. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't execute the two functions attached for the two ajax requests (it executes the third function and then the other two).

Any ideas?

Comment: Promisify the success callbacks of both ajax calls and put them into the $q.all

Comment: are you using angular $q promise library??

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery Promises,which provide a better and more flexible solution for this type of problem.

Demo code:

```
 var promiseOne, promiseTwo;
    // Promises
    promiseOne = $.ajax({ url: '../test.html' });
    promiseTwo = $.ajax({ url: '../test.html' });

   // $.when() creates a new promise which will be:
    // resolved if both promises inside are resolved
    // rejected if one of the promises fails
    $.when(
        promiseOne,
        promiseTwo
    )
    .done(function () {          //.done() is callback for resolve state
        console.log('promiseOne and promiseTwo are done');
    })
    .fail(function () {   //.fail() is callback for reject state 
        console.log('One of our promises failed');
    });
```

Instead of using .done() & fail(), use can use .then() which also return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I will to do it with angular $watch.
$watch call a given fonction each time the watched variable(s) is/are modified :

```
$scope.req1ok = false ;  
$scope.req1ok = false ;  

$http(request1).success(function (status) {
    $scope.req1ok = true ;  
}).error(function (status) {
    ...
});

$http(request2).success(function (status) {
    $scope.req2ok = true ;  
}).error(function (status) {
    ...
});

$scope.$watchCollection('[req1ok,req2ok]', function () {
    // when request1 and request2 done complety
    if($scope.req1ok && $scope.req2ok){
      // do what you want
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a transpiler like babel? If so, I would recommend to use the yield syntax.

```
[this.scope.result1, this.scope.result2] =
          yield [
            this.myService.getResult1(),
            this.myService.getResult()
          ]

 console.debug("Here, we have both the results ready")
```

If not, you probably have to do it manually either using a counter or chain the callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

Here i have call a function in both success event but function works only when temp =2, Please try these code and let me know your issue if any :-

```
var temp = 0;

// first ajax code
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html"
}).success(function() {
   if (temp == 0)
   {
     temp =1;
   }
   else
   {
     temp =2;
   }
   afterSuccess();
});

// Second ajax call
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html"
}).success(function() {
   if (temp == 1)
   {
     temp =2;
   }
   else
   {
     temp =1;
   }
   afterSuccess();
});
```

Now if we complete both request then we have temp = 2;

so do your code with that condition

```
function afterSuccess()
{
    if (temp == 2)
    {
       // do your code
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do the  "if (temp == 2){}" test only when both ajax requests are done in pure javascript ?

Comment: You can test with IF condition in pure javascript also, can you tell me what is the problem in that?

Comment: you have to do the test when the both requests are finish with a promise or something like that. just putting this test after the two $.ajax() will fail because it will execute the test before the ajax calls are finishes

Comment: exactly so if you put your "if (temp == 2){}" just after the $ajax it always be false. you need to use promise or similar mecanism.

Comment: if both finish in the same time it will not work; i think better to use two boolean and make tham true when call 1 and call 2 are finish. and then in afterSuccess() test is both are true

Comment: Yes you can do that to use two different variable for each. :)